# Getting 404 on files from _next/... after building app as standalone and running in production env

Tags: next.js13

I am running a Next.js app in a Docker container, using `output: 'standalone'` in the next.config.js file. I am seeing several errors in the browser console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` on URLs like `http://localhost:3000/_next/data/-EjBmZC_sUNABJlyVFLrD/en.json`. There is nothing in the container logs.

Other repeating URLs are like:
`http://localhost:3000/_next/static/HohSA5NklVOnW4XgbV_49/_buildManifest.js`,
`http://localhost:3000/_next/static/HohSA5NklVOnW4XgbV_49/_ssgManifest.js`

I can go to pages that are working fine, but still get 1 or more of these errors in the console.

Here is my next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/**'
      }
    ]
  },
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en"],
    defaultLocale: "en"
  },
  output: "standalone"
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Here is the docker file:

```
FROM node:19-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
COPY .env.production .env.production
RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I have tried running it outside of a docker container, just doing `npm run build` and `node server.js`, but I get the same results as when using the Docker container. I can't figure out what is going on. The errors do not show when I run it in development mode using `npm run dev`.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I am similar problem you can check my recently asked question.